# Drop Down Menu Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the html for two drop down menus.

```
<div id="selects">
            <div id="select1Div" style="float:left;margin-right:15px;"> Select
              Your &lt;Desired pet&gt; <br>
              <select name="firstSelect" id="firstSelect">
                <option>----</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div id="select2Div"> Select Your &lt;Gender&gt;
              <br>
              <select name="secondSelect" id="secondSelect">
                <option>----</option>
                &nbsp;
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br>
```

I am new to javascript, so could someone please help point me in the right direction as how to start with the coding portion of this?  All I want to do is add cat and dog under the desired pet drop down, and male or female under the gender option.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: so it's just about positioning those things at the right place? if so you don't need javascript you will need css

Comment: Dropdown menus don't generally employ selects. Like caramba said, use CSS and switch to lists. There are many fine examples online.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically need to use JavaScript to do it, you may write something like this:

```
$('#firstSelect')
    .append('<option value="cat">Cat</option>')
    .append('<option value="dog">Dog</option>');

$('#secondSelect')
    .append('<option value="m">Male</option>')
    .append('<option value="f">Female</option>');
```

Using JavaScript for that only makes sense when you want to respond to an event, an ajax call or adding options dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstSelect = document.getElementById("firstSelect");
firstSelect.innerHTML += "<option>Cat</option>";
firstSelect.innerHTML += "<option>Dog</option>";

var secondSelect = document.getElementById("secondSelect");
secondSelect.innerHTML += "<option>Male</option>";
secondSelect.innerHTML += "<option>Female</option>";
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/w5Dq2/)